# run JQuery dialog window from code behind

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I'd like to open dialog window from code behind in a button onClick.  How to run the script?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <div id="dialog" title="Alert!!!" style="display: none;">
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum
        </p>
    </div>

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.ImageButton1.Click += new System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(this.ImageButton1_Click);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
        }

        private void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "script", "$(function() {$('#dialog').dialog('open');});", true);
        }
```

Comment: I've tried to write onClickScript to a button. In this method, I can easily open dialog. But in server, It doesn't worked. Nowly, I want to open dialog in code behind.

Comment: @Nix The project was written .Net 2.0. I can not debug the code. I don't know what the error is.

Comment: Not sure why you'd need to use code behind for this. Have you tried using `onClientClick` property of the `asp:Button` control and put your client side script in there, or a JS function call to open a dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "script", "<script> $('#dialog').dialog('open');return false;  </script>");
```

Comment: its System.Web.UI and use the page object, if you are using ajax then use ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock